# Simple windows dll with function I can wrap

Tags: windows, dll

I wish to test python's ctypes by wrapping a function from a windows dll. Is there a windows dll, available on windows vista, which I could test with? For example, perhaps the dll has a function that returns the current time in string form.

If not, I guess I will have to write my own dll in C and Visual Studio Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest to wrap will be the message box function: it is practically the hello-world of dll wrapping. It lives in `user32.dll`. Take a look [here](http://www.glbasic.com/forum/index.php?topic=2129.0)